# y component of Vector3 doesn't match

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this coroutine to calculate the velocity

```
    IEnumerator CalcVelocity()
    {
            prevPos = transform.position;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            print(((prevPos - transform.position) / Time.deltaTime));
            print(((prevPos - transform.position) / Time.deltaTime).y);
            velocity = Mathf.Abs(((prevPos - transform.position) / Time.deltaTime).y);
    }
```

I'm printing out the velocity in all directions and then the y velocity as that's the only I need for my purpose.

However sometimes the serialized Vector3 and the y component don't match - as below they are wildly different. The y value seems to be completely wrong.

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) // the Vector3 printout

8.488064E-05 // the y
```

What's gone wrong here?

Comment: Whats known as floating point issues. While in our head it should be simple. It never is quite as simple as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

> What's gone wrong here?
> Nothing, it's just how unity show things in your log

If you run this

```
public void Test()
{
    var v = new Vector3(0f, 0.00001f, 0f);
    var y = v.y;
    
    Debug.Log($"{v}");
    Debug.Log($"{y}");
}
```

You will see this
[image]

If you want to see more than 1 decimal, you can use formatters

```
public void Test()
{
    var v = new Vector3(0f, 0.00001f, 0f);
    var y = v.y;
    
    Debug.Log($"{v.ToString("F5")}");
    Debug.Log($"{y}");
}
```

[image]

N

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong.

The default implementation of `Vector3.ToString` uses a human readable rounded display (see [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L463))

> ```
>     public override string ToString()
>     {
>         return ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
>     }
>
>     public string ToString(string format)
>     {
>         return ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
>     }
>
>     public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
>     {
>         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
>             format = "F1";
>         return UnityString.Format("({0}, {1}, {2})", x.ToString(format, formatProvider), y.ToString(format, formatProvider), z.ToString(format, formatProvider));
>     }
> ```

As you can see by default it uses [`"F1"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#fixed-point-format-specifier-f) meaning fixed floating point format rounded to a single decimal.

You can provide any custom format you want like e.g.

```
print(((prevPos - transform.position) / Time.deltaTime).ToString("G9"));
```

Where ["G"](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#general-format-specifier-g) is the general formatter allowing to either print scientific or fixed point presentation depending on which one is more compact.

By chosing `G9` it ensures that the `float` values are printed and then if they would get parsed again would always successfully roundtrip without any data loss.

For more information about available formatting strings see [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [Custom Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)